# Adding to retrieved ArrayLists

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, indexing

Here is the line

```
waves.get(selectedWave - 1).add(selectedMonster + selectedMosnterLevel);
```

waves is an

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

which means it holds other lists of integers. My problem is, that when i retrieve a specific list of Integers by invoking

```
waves.get(index)
```

and then adding an Integer value to it

```
waves.get(index).add(anInt)
```

it adds "anInt" to every single list, which is present in the "waves" list. Is this really how it works, or might i be screwing up somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Show us how are you populating the `List`.

Comment: Are you calling waves.get(index) in a loop?

Comment: you are screwing up somewhere else in your code, sure.

Comment: @pippin1289 no only in the game loop

Comment: @TheNewIdiot This is how i populate the list, nowhere else

Comment: You are certainly adding the reference to the same list in your list.

Comment: Ok, it seems (by the comments) my code is ok, but I am screwing up somewhere else, Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

> it adds "anInt" to every single list, which is present in the "waves" list.

The only plausible reason I can think of is that all the `List<Integer>` references which are added to the `List<List<Integer>>` points to the same `List<Integer>` object . The code below will result in this behavior :

```
List<List<Integer>> waves = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = list1;
waves.add(list1);
waves.add(list1);
waves.add(list2);
```